# Node render process gone while downloading files

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, electron

I'm programming a small Electron program, that (currently) is able to download multiple big files from Google Drive. Some files are too big to be scanned so it tricks the server into believing the "Download anyway" button was clicked.

The problem is, that after 3, 7 or 12 files, the Chrome Dev Tools window shows "Render process gone".

3 files:
- download unblocking turned on while trying to download the same blocked file 3 times in a row. The 4th file crashes.

7 files:
- mixture of 5 non-blocked files and 2 blocked ones with download unblocking turned on. The 8th file (non-blocked) request crashes

12 files:
- downloading 9 non-blocked files and 3 blocked ones while download unblocking turned off

Therefore, I came to conclude, that "unblocking" a file takes up 3 of the 12 possible "slots". Then, everything (or at least the numbers) would make sense.

Unblocking works by sending another request with the same cookie char and a ?confirm=xxxx at the same url.

Note that the whole thing doesn't crash after 12 files if I use another file provider with 100mb test files.

It would be extremely helpful if you could point me in the right direction.

Here's a really simplified version of the code that's used. Note that a lot of variable declarations and other stuff is missing, but these parts seem to be the problematic ones:

```js
// downloadmanager.js
function DownloadManager(pack) {
  var _this = this;


  this.downloadpackages = function (package, data, cb) {
    sync.fiber(function () {

      ...

      Object.keys(ht_distinct_urls).forEach(function (url) {
        localfile = sync.await(_this.download(remotefile, sync.defer()));
        console.log("Downloaded:" + localfile);
      });
    });
  }


  this.dl = function (remotefile, cb) {
    request(request_options, (err, response, body) => {
      // cb() in this location makes it crash at the 13th file
      cb(null, "");
    });

    // cb() in this location doesnt make it crash (but also not download anything)
    //cb(null, "");
  }

  this.download = function (remotefile, cb) {
    // Try to download
    _this.dl(remotefile, function (err, data) {
      if (data.downloaded) { // It worked
        cb(err, data);
      } else if (data.unblocked) { // It was able to get a code to unblock it
        _this.dl(data, cb); // Try again with the new cookie and the code
      } else {
        // Fck it, just return the data anyway for debugging
        cb(err, data);
      }
    });
  };
}



// renderer.js
sync.fiber(function () {
  var pack = getPackage();

  var dm = new DownloadManager(pack);

  var download_result = sync.await(dm.downloadpackages(pack, ht_distinct_urls, sync.defer()));
  console.log(download_result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems like I found a solution while posting this question. I'll just post it anyway, maybe it helps someone else...

It seems like google blocks instant downloading. Adding a timeout of 5 seconds between downloads solved my problem. Haven't tested how low the timeout can be, but maybe the problem was solved by the settimeout callback anyway...

Comment: In this we may have a clue about what’s going on. Sometimes you just need to let the main JS thread “catch its breath”. By using `setTimeout` you’re effectively *deferring* your function. Maybe a `setTimeout(..., 0)` would be enough, give it a try. Don’t worry about this `0`, browsers cap it to their minimal value (usually 10ms but my info might not be up-to-date).

Comment: I try, but that doesn't work for me, but I set time to 10ms and it work